# How to make SAS to open with maximized window?

Tags: sas, display-manager

How to make SAS to open with the main window and the editor window automatically maximized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to push the command AWSMAXIMIZE at startup.  You could place this statement in your autoexec.sas

dm "awsmaximize";

I was also able to do this by editing the start menu entry and adding to the end of the SAS command: -initstmt "dm 'awsmaximize';"

More here: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000115355.htm#win-af-wincmds

Comment: I forgot to add you can also push commands to maximize the program editor.  See the doc link and related commands.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can do this automatically at startup, but you can set a hotkey to do it.

Tools -> Options -> Keys

Choose a key and type this into the command:

```
AWSMAXIMIZE ON; WPGM; ZOOM
```

1. "AWSMAXIMIZE ON" is the SAS for Windows command to maximize itself.
2. "WPGM" is the command to bring focus to the Enhanced Program Manager
3. "ZOOM" is the command to maximize the in-focus window.

Comment: John beat me to the submit on this.  If you combine our two answers you have what you need!